# Ubuntu 20.04 top bar weird display calendar

Tags: 20.04, display-manager, taskbar, notification-area

A picture speaks a thousand words: why is the calendar transparent and generally weird display? If the background isn't white, the calendar is unreadable

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is it always like that or happens after some specific trigger?

Comment: @RishabhKumar its always like that

Comment: Did you tried changing gnome-shell theme?

Comment: It may be useful to know what exact version of GNOME Shell You're using and if You use Wayland or not. Could You provide that information?

I think I would also start from trying to change a theme as @jaga-matrix already suggested. You can also try changing from Wayland or to a Wayland session to see if it changes anything and - possibly obviously - updating a GNOME Shell if it's not in a newest available version.

Comment: @kcpr Ubuntu 20.04.2, Gnome 3.36.8. I notice this problem is mainly when any window is present. i.e. on normal desktop its fine, but once theres a program filling the screen this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04 seems to fix the issue for me